# Error: Could not symlink bin/dvipdf when installing Octave

Tags: macos, homebrew

Note: A question similar to this one was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509856/error-could-not-symlink-bin-dvipdf-when-installing-octave) about a week ago.

I am attempting to install Octave on OS X Mavericks.  I ran the following:

```
brew install octave
```

which resulted in this error:

```
Error: You must `brew link ghostscript' before octave can be installed
```

So I followed this advice, which gave this output:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.15... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/dvipdf
Target /usr/local/bin/dvipdf
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm /usr/local/bin/dvipdf

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite ghostscript

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run ghostscript
```

I ran the last option, which printed a really long list of files.  I think these files might be related to my recent install of *MacTeX*, which worries me.

Comment: I have a similar issue (although not installing Octave, but have the brew conflict with ghostscript).  You're right that it has to do with MacTex, but I am not sure the best answer, as I stumbled across this question to also try to solve my own issue.